# Fortran filter a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran

the two dimensional array I am talking about holds values such as

```
1   2326
1   2331
1   2328
1   2323
2   2404
2   2398
2   2401
2   2403
3   2408
3   2401
3   2408
3   2401
```

I want to operate on all the elements that have the same id at a time, like:

```
program filter_2d
    integer(1000, 1000) :: my_array
    integer :: id

    ...

    print *, any(my_array(1, :), id)
end program filter_2d
```

any just returns true. How can i filter the rows that have (i, 1) == 2 for example?

and as a side question, should I be using arrays or just go with a custom type that has an id integer and an array to hold the rest of the values (the array is much larger irl, like 10000x10000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to go is a loop and an if statement:

```
program filter_2d
  integer             :: my_array(3, 3)
  integer, parameter  :: id = 2

  my_array = reshape( [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [3,3] )

  do i=1,size(my_array,1)
    if ( my_array(i,1) == id ) print *, my_array(i, :)
  enddo ! i
end program filter_2d
```

Especially if the dimensions become larger I would use arrays instead of derived types. An OOP approach always has a computational overhead that needs to be considered.

As a rule of thumb I always use structures as simple as possible, and only choose derived types if I see no other option. This, of course, only applies to the numerics part of the code. For the organization of simulations including I/O and pre-processing it is usually beneficial to adopt an OOP paradigm.

---

You can also set up an index set and operate on that:

```
program filter_2d
  integer             :: my_array(3, 3)
  integer, parameter  :: id = 2

  integer             :: idx( size(my_array, 1) )
  integer             :: nMatch

  my_array = reshape( [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [3,3] )

  nMatch = 0
  do i=1,size(my_array,1)
    if ( my_array(i,1) == id ) then
      nMatch = nMatch + 1
      idx(nMatch) = i
    endif
  enddo ! i

  print *, my_array(idx(:nMatch),:) 
end program filter_2d
```

This can probably be written a more elegantly, but you get the idea...

Comment: not sure how the any(my_array(i, :), id) works here, isn't any supposed to have a logical expression?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with `any`... `any( my_array(1, :) == id  )` would be true if any of the elements of the first row is `id`. You get a single true/false decision, not an index set!

Comment: I was trying to use any to return a reduced array with only the rows that matched its expression, but I suppose that is not possible?

Comment: `any` returns a scalar logical, not an index set!

Comment: yeah, I thought if you applied dim, it would return an array instead of t/f. I come from a python background and fortran always twists things :D

Comment: If you apply the dimension, you get a `rank-1` array back. In principle, you apply `any` on all rows or columns. Since you pass a 1D array, you would still get a 0D array back...